# Function to add fees to cart for Woocommerce subscription

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am struggling with a function to add fees to a Woocommerce Subscription, based on the number of other products in the cart. When I run it I get a critical error on the site. Can anyone see why?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_administration_fees', 10, 1 );

function add_administration_fees( $cart ) {

    /* First I try to sum the number of products in the cart that are NOT subscriptions */

    $item_count = 0;
    
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if (!$item->is_type('subscription')) {
            $item_count++;
        }
    } 

/* Then I try to add $50 per extra product to the Initial Order Fee */
    
    if ( empty( $cart->recurring_cart_key ) ) {
        $cart->add_fee( 'Additional Items', $item_count * 50 );
    }
    
/* Then I try to add $7 per extra product to the Recurring Monthly Fee (if the cart is on page 254) or $5 per extra product (if the cart is on page 457) */

    if ( is_page(254)) {
        if ( ! empty( $cart->recurring_cart_key ) ) {
            $cart->add_fee( 'Additional Items', $item_count * 7 );
        }
    }
    
    if ( is_page(457)) {
        if ( ! empty( $cart->recurring_cart_key ) ) {
            $cart->add_fee( 'Additional Items', $item_count * 5 );
        }
    }
    

}
```

Comment: This hook is only for cart page. is_page doesnt make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems with your code.

1. This hook is used on cart and checkout page and is_page(some ID) doesnt make sense.
2. $item is not product object so you cant use is_type()

Since its unclear what you are trying to do this should be a good starting point

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_administration_fees' );
function add_administration_fees() {
    if(!WC()->cart->is_empty()) {
        $item_count = 0;
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            // We need product object
            $product = $cart_item['data'];
            //replace with w.e product type you want
            if(!$product->is_type('subscription')) {
                $item_count++;
            }
        }
        
        //Add fee only if we have products other than subscription
        if($item_count > 0) {
            WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Additional Items', $item_count * 50 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Martin. I've managed to get the item_count to work, but still struggling with the other part of adding subscription fees based on which subscription product is in the cart. I added what I've tried as another answer as it wouldn't fit in a comment here.

Comment: well depends on how you devide those subscriptions you can either check price or other meta for the product and add your logic conditions . If they are in different categories for example you can check by that too.